# ReactJS child components import resolution along with their parent component prefix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, es6-modules

Hi folks I'm very curious to find a way for importing parent/child components with the prefix of their parent component using dot notation.

Before taking your much time I would like to show you guys an example from the `react-bootstrap` components import style.

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap";

# usage

function Example() {
  return (
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer></Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

I'm trying to have this kind of a similar approach.

I have a `Layout` component and within that, I have 3 more child components `Header`, `Body`, and `Footer`.

Right now I'm using them like this

Layout.js

```
export const Header = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="header">{children}</div>
);

export const Body = ({ children }) => <div className="body">{children}</div>;

export const Footer = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="footer">{children}</div>
);

export const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return <section>{children}</section>;
};

const _default = {
  Header: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
  Body: (props) => <Body {...props} />,
  Footer: (props) => <Footer {...props} />
};

export default _default;
```

App.js

```
import { Layout, Header, Body, Footer } from "./Layout";
import ParentLayout from "./Layout";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <Header>Header goes here</Header>
        <Body>Body goes here</Body>
        <Footer>Footer goes here</Footer>
      </Layout>
      {/* as you can see from this example i can't use ParentLayout as a componet */}
      <Layout>
        <ParentLayout.Header>Header goes here</ParentLayout.Header>
        <ParentLayout.Body>Body goes here</ParentLayout.Body>
        <ParentLayout.Footer>Footer goes here</ParentLayout.Footer>
      </Layout>
      {/* so i was wondering if it can be done in this way */}
      {/* 
        <ParentLayout>
          <ParentLayout.Header>Header goes here</ParentLayout.Header>
          <ParentLayout.Body>Body goes here</ParentLayout.Body>
          <ParentLayout.Footer>Footer goes here</ParentLayout.Footer>
        </ParentLayout> 
      */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-sky-2yzyck?file=/src/App.js) playground so you can quickly hit and try.

Comment: It's much easier than you think: `function Layout(props) { ... }` then simply `Layout.Header = function(props) { ... };`: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-goodall-z4ecyh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks!
Okay, I'm agreed but then how I will use child components?
Of course, I can import them and use them but I don't wanna do this I have already imported their parent component now I want to use its child components like this `<Layout.Header>Header goes here</Layout.Header>`

Comment: I added the codesandbox, but all you need to do is import Layout.